# Find from one directory to another

Tags: python, list, csv, directory

I am trying to read a huge list output from a file directory, and once it finds it, it place it in another file using python.

I have a huge data set and was able to split the csv to 3 different folders based on their classes.

I need to search the list of column images and find from a directory and place it in a new file

To make everything clear:

```
class0.csv ,Unnamed: 0,noise,rot_ratio,background,class,images
0,0,0.031495803,0.383730466,0.870530701,0,00859199-ad58-4334-8635-07a094e11f94.JPG
5,5,2.605760607,0.547664714,-0.59016648,0,03159229-f613-4bd2-be32-82cf65496865.JPG
13,13,0.79224368,0.742954625,1.136200214,0,083ba0e4-cf97-40b7-9de3-0cdb618006c5.JPG
18,18,-0.416518561,0.432365614,1.12786556,0,0a9bca0f-dcbd-458e-a2bf-557876e5b402.JPG
36,36,2.192400275,0.558622462,-1.038830864,0,0e96c5b0-2ea6-441c-a1b6-22b5f650347b.JPG
46,46,-0.575673656,0.429221735,1.348484522,0,152c3bd4-dc1b-4328-a303-d923c226c040.JPG
51,51,3.880669006,0.295885257,1.005818478,0,19424685-3776-472c-8b07-f4c01643424e.JPG
53,53,1.552991557,0.485258419,0.282584728,0,1a8be963-4696-4605-826a-b9c1999985ae.JPG
```

Todo:
I need to find the images from my file directory and place it in another file, as the file contains images from different classes.
Hope it is clear.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('class0.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) # read rows into a dictionary format
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
        for (k,v) in row.items(): # go over each column name and value 
            columns[k].append(v) # append the value into the appropriate list
                                 # based on column name k
image = columns['images']
print(image)
```

output list

```
'00859199-ad58-4334-8635-07a094e11f94.JPG', '03159229-f613-4bd2-be32-82cf65496865.JPG', '083ba0e4-cf97-40b7-9de3-0cdb618006c5.JPG', '0a9bca0f-dcbd-458e-a2bf-557876e5b402.JPG', '0e96c5b0-2ea6-441c-a1b6-22b5f650347b.JPG', '152c3bd4-dc1b-4328-a303-d923c226c040.JPG', '19424685-3776-472c-8b07-f4c01643424e.JPG', '1a8be963-4696-4605-826a-b9c1999985ae.JPG', '1d5c3c21-77d1-42d8-a4fc-80e8db01e2f2.JPG', '1ec36552-00af-454a-af47-de600baf3f1b.JPG', '2acbdc0e-9ae9-47e3-9dc3-c6a124c19296.JPG', '2c9e886e-ac63-4c60-b959-b7bccdd20289.JPG', '2df13128-ff88-4813-973b-c83296f1cbf5.JPG', '2eb9f4b7-cabc-4cd8-98b9-2f3470d623d2.JPG', '3169cf83-c70c-48b6-8332-9cae259e2204.JPG', '339371b4-c470-4489-832a-acd1d9c68d9f.JPG', '3504dc2b-8516-4ffc-bf02-9972409cfb0b.JPG', '364b3c69-dc6a-4afb-b67c-eb0854b5eaaf.JPG', '38cae58c-c150-4e39-a319-a57db3d9ac5f.JPG', '3ee6554f-3d7b-4094-844f-9539cc97a286.JPG', '444ea9ce-cdb5-4f48-ae28-d18e247bc6e4.JPG', '4513be86-e1ee-46a1-8897-30101045b420.JPG', '4e587d28-9656-47cc-bcac-93de429c3847.JPG', '4f4d7096-a3d7-49fe-90c8-63faed85d66c.JPG'
```

Now, I have a folder with many images including the output list. I want to find those specific images from main folder and place it in a new one.

Done so far: (I need to read the list output and find it from source_dir folder and place the specific files to target_dir)

```
import shutil
import os
    
source_dir = '/images'
target_dir = 'class0'
    
file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)
    
for file_name in file_names:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)
```

I need to place only the specific images from output list

Comment: There's no `names` column in the CSV file.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: So should `columns['names']` be `columns['images']`? How does that relate to the question?

Comment: i need to find the files (.jpg, etc) from one directory and place it in another. Now I have them as list. I will edit the post to make it clear!

Comment: What do you mean by "place it in another file"? Do you mean copy the image file? Use `shutil.copy()` to copy a file.

Comment: Where is your code that tries to do this, so we can help you fix it?

Comment: I don't know how to start! I was able to split the big csv file and all, but I dont know how to read from list output and find it in directory and then place those images to another file. Like the concept is clear, just having bad time executing it! hints would be appreciated